# curl command for bin/post any file

Tags: curl, solr

This is what I've done:

```
$ bin/solr start
$ bin/solr create -c mytest
$ bin/post -c mytest -filetypes py,js ~/Projects
```

As a result, I can now make queries and search through *.py and *.js files in one of my home directories. I know, that if contents of one of the files has changed, I can update index via this command:

```
$ bin/post -c mytest ~/path_to_the_file  # this is what I try to achive with curl
```

All these steps are absolutely ok. However, the problem is - I do not know and I can not find in the documentation the way how I can achive the same result as the last command above, which updates the index. In the command line I see how collection can be created through curl and on Solr Admin page I see how I can make requests through curl to query the index. But the last command lacks documentation.

Comment: By the way, I've seen examples where people index json and xml files through curl, but they use `-H "Content-Type: ..."`. It will be great, if someone knows what content type to use for arbitrary files, like *.py and *.js

Comment: I tried dozens combinations of this sort: `$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/collection1/update/?commit=true --data-binary @filepath - H "Content-type:..."`. I tried json, xml,csv content types, I tried no content type at all, but none of these methods works. I hope, someone has this sacred knowledge, which is not present in documentation.

Comment: Judging by all I can see in many blogs and threads, there is a complete mess with solr syntax in this area. In some case you can use `csv` in url, if its extension is not "ordinary", then you have to use some magic like `-F "myfile=@path_to_the_file"` or something like `?stream.file=blablbabla`. So, I wonder if Solr documentation is helpful at all, if it does not contain trivial use cases and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, somewhere in the Ocean of forums, threads and blogs I found a solution. The right way to index a plain (unstructured) text file is this one:

```
$ curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8983:/solr/collection1/update/extract/?literal.id=
any_document_id_you_like&commit=true' -F 'myfile=@path_to_the_file_you_want_to_index'
```

That works as expected. I wish there was something about this way of doing things in the documentation.